# Get value from key in script result run by python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am writing a script in python which fetches index information from MongoDB collection, here my script

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import dbconfig
import sys
import os

prod = MongoClient(dbconfig.prod_url)

result_index = prod['testcms']['assess'].index_information()
['assessment'].index_information()

print("index count is, ",result_index)
```

and result which i got is this,

```
('index count is, ', {u'submitted_time_1': {u'background': True, u'key': [(u'submitted_time', 1.0)], u'v': 2, u'ns': u'testcms.assess', u'sparse': True}, u'attempt_id_hashed': {u'ns': u'testcms.assess', u'key': [(u'attempt_id', 1)], u'v': 2, u'unique': True, u'background': True}, u'_id_': {u'ns': u'testcms.assess', u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 2}, u'worksheet_id_1': {u'key': [(u'worksheet_id', 1)], u'ns': u'testcms.assess', u'background': True, u'v': 2}, u'submitter_id_hashed': {u'ns': u'testcms.assess', u'key': [(u'submitter_id', u'hashed')], u'v': 2}})
```

Now I want to show/fetch only specific values from this entire result and those values are,

**1. submitter_id_hashed**

**2. submitted_time_1**

**3. attempt_id_hashed**

**4. worksheet_id_1**

How can I show this following values only on output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first, declare a list of your wanted key:

```
list = ["submitter_id_hashed", "submitted_time_1", "attempt_id_hashed", "worksheet_id_1"]
```

the use this:

```
result = {key: result[key] for key in list}
```

Comment: This is a snippet of the code

`result_index = prod['testcms']['assess'].index_information()

list = ["submitter_id_hashed", "submitted_time_1", "attempt_id_hashed", "worksheet_id_1"]
result_index = {key: result_index[key] for key in list}
print(result_index)`

and same output as above with lots of unwanted data, Not giving specific values as required

Comment: I've tested it. for example test result_index["\_id\_"]

Answer (score 0):

Just access them using keys

```
result_index["submitter_id_hashed"]
result_index["submitted_time_1"]
result_index["attempt_id_hashed"]
result_index["worksheet_id_1"]
```